# "AOL is unable to verify this website" when logging in to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login, openid

For about a few weeks now, I've been getting the warning message "AOL is unable to verify this website" when I try to use AOL as my OpenID provider to log in into Stack Overflow. It happens on both IE on Windows 7 and an iPad, so it doesn't appear to be related to cookies, etc.

Some cursory searches indicate that this might be a problem (disagreement?) between AOL and Stack Overflow itself. It doesn't look that this is a problem with the account.

Is this something that is been looked into by the SE staff? Or is it an AOL problem?

Comment: The problem has gone away in the last few days. Someone must have fixed the issue either from the SE side, or from the AOL side. Feel free to flag as "resolved".